# Are Auth Tokens App Specific?

Tags: facebook, authentication, auth-token

I'm in the process of developing an app that will allow users to perform a lot of the same actions of our website (slimmed down, of course) but we're also toying with the idea of adding a facebook login FOR our website.  From what I've read, allowing facebook logins requires you to submit your website and get an app id.  So now I will have 2 app IDs with different types of permissions (the app permissions will have multiple, login will only have basic) for each, will I be able to just store 1 access token for a user (whichever has the higher level of permissions) or do I need to store both?

From what I can tell, I'll only need 1, but I I'd like to get some insight before beginning this process.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication tokens are application specific. One possible alternative for you is to use the [Developer application](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) to enable your application to be both an "app on Facebook" and a "Website" (see the *Select how your app integrates with Facebook* section). This would enable you to use the same application ID both on your website and in the Facebook canvas application.

Comment: Ah, that would be perfect.  Thanks so much for clearing this up.